# Can SQL Server master key be recreated from password?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am setting up encrypted backups on SQL Server 2014. I will create a database master key (CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='...') and then an asymmetric key. Microsoft recommends keeping an off-site backup of the master key.

If I have the password used to create the master key, but not the backed-up master key itself, can I recreate the master key, or would the backups become inaccessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it cannot.

The command is really broken up like this:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY
                  ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '...'
```

The first part creates a new random key, the second part encrypts it for storage in the database. The password is not used to *generate* the key, it is used to protect it.

As such, if you lose the key, you cannot recreate it.